# Why 2021 top-tier road bike are so dark? Is black/dark better looking or good looking is nothing at all anymore?

Tags: shopping

Why 2021 new road bike are so black and dark? And, most of them, the bike brand is even invisible.

The kind of color makes the bike looks like a "semi-finished product" (un-painting product).

Not only one big bike company does so, many major bike brands do so.

I am a buyer and I hope to know if it is a new trend and the reason behind the trend.

S-Works Tarmac SL7 2021

[image]

S-Works Diverge

[image]

Giant Advenced TCR SL0 2021

[image]

Cervelo Caledonia-5

[image]

Canyon Ultimate CFR Disc Di2

[image]

BMC Timemachine SLR 01 Frameset

[image]

You can find more and they are really dark, don't they?

Is it better looking?

Why bike brand should be hidden?

Comment: I think it's a result of the customers wanting such colors. It fits with the current trend where for a lot of riders aesthetics are as important as performance and fitness

Comment: Fashion, but changing the colour and not much else means you can also convince Cashed up MAMIL's to fork out another few grand on a new bike the want, but do not need, and pocket the profit.

Comment: I am good at riding and have good fitting. But I also used to take photography with every riding. I go out, ride and take photos. But, the kind of painting is not good for photography. It is just dark and all are the same .. like uniform.... Not good for photographing biker.

Comment: I think your only option is having a custom frame built. If you're truly desperate, you might even have a look at manufacturer websites and see that these bikes do have other color options too.

Comment: Yes, they have but not the top tiers especially specialized's. Their allez bikes have beautiful and brilliant colors.

Comment: Thank you for all your comment. Actually I have just purchased one of the bike in the pictures above, I just need to find a reson to convince myself to accept the dark-tone colorset. Thank you all and I am very appreciated.

Comment: @CrayKao shine a light on it from the side, in the dark.  That's how visible it is at night.   There's a chance there's reflective parts, but also not guaranteed.  For safety's sake, ride with active lights AND fit passive spoke reflectors - those white cylinders, not the chunky yellow plastic that are fitted to most bikes sold.

Comment: @Criggie Tires with reflective sidewalls are also good - the dual hoops of reflected light will make you easily identifiable.

Comment: Another advantage - dark colours don't fade like the bright ones sometimes do.

Comment: After more collection, I think this is not just a coincidence, but a new trend deliberately designed like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short and, I am afraid, only answer is "fashion". The "tan" walls on the tires that are present on the two first images are another trait of the fashion.

There is nothing wrong with that, but, if you really are on high-end bicycle market, there are smaller manufacturers and third-party companies ready to customize your frame paint. Customization services like Orbea MyO come directly from the vendor.

> And, most of them, the bike brand is even invisible.

Personally, I am fine with that: I hate being a moving advertisement for anything.

Comment: "I hate being a moving advertisement for anything." <-- It seems to be the key resaon behind the "fashion" since only the most top-tier's color set is so. (Specialized and Giant).

Comment: "I hate being a moving advertisement for anything." <-- It is a good reason. But, with the kind of "fashion" it will make everybody has uniform-like bikes - all dark-tone like the pictures as above. All are uniform / business-suit like is really bad. I will go for customized solution for my bike. It forces me to spend much time and effort but maybe it should be so.

Comment: >But, with the kind of "fashion" it will make everybody has uniform-like bikes. — First of all, the highest end bicycles are not "everybody", it is barely somebody. The absolute majority of people ride anything but these. As it is with high fashion in clothes, nobody in their right mind will go out in a "dress" shown on a catwalk, unless they have a reason for that. 

Secondly, even these 4 bikes on the pictures above are not black, they are vastly different. Some of them have very colorful rainbow shine. I am sure they all look gorgeous in reality, not through the web browser window.

Comment: Does it make sense to answer and vote to close as off-topic at the same time?

Comment: I am not the one closing the question. And, the question is just clear and specific and no more and no less. Now, I just wish it will not be deleted.

Comment: @CrayKao All fashion is inherently opnion-based. Besides, there is always enough bikes of different colours, even top ones. Bianchi's have there own traditional colours, for example, Trek also makes traditional red ones and so on.

Comment: I didn't go here to look for some shopping opinion or like but YES, i did like to know the reason behind the trend. Actually, here is the best place to help me a lot finding the answer. I am really appreciated all comments and the answer.